# Counting characters with StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string

I need to write a function that counts the frequency of each letter in a string.

This is an example:

I receive the file:  notes.txt   message included:  " Hello this is Jack from Nebraska "

When I read the file, this is the result:

a: 3
H: 1
e: 2
l: 2
etc

Someone tell me that I can use the Stringtokeizer, is this true?

Comment: It is true. There are also many other ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Would you please provide some of your own code? We aren't going to do everything for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing information in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303174/writing-information-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    String str = "Hello this is Jack from Nebraska";

    Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (!frequencies.containsKey(c))
            frequencies.put(c, 1);
        else
            frequencies.put(c, frequencies.get(c) + 1);
    }

    System.out.println(frequencies);
}
```

Output:

```
{f=1,  =5, e=2, b=1, c=1, a=3, o=2, N=1, l=2, m=1, H=1, k=2, h=1, J=1, i=2, t=1, s=3, r=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Multiset/Bag data structure approach. Using Guava it would look like:

```
public static void main(String... a) {
    final String str = "Hello this is Jack from Nebraska";

    final Builder<Character> b = ImmutableMultiset.builder();           
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        b.add(c);

    System.out.println(b.build());
}
```

Results in:

`[H, e x 2, l x 2, o x 2,   x 5, t, h, i x 2, s x 3, J, a x 3, c, k x 2, f, r x 2, m, N, b]`

Comment: David, are there any easier way to do it without any complex code ?

Comment: @dacwe I believe that is result of the formatting of the post, not exactly how the output looks.