# Writing information in a String

Tags: java, file

I need to save lines into a String

Ex:

```
public function countOccurrences() {

    String Message = "Hello, how are you?"
    String trim = Mensaje.replaceAll(" ", "");


    char[] third = trim.toCharArray();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < third.length; counter++) {

        char ch = third[counter];
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < third.length; i++) {

            if (ch == third[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }


        boolean flag = false;
        for (int j = counter - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (ch == third[j]) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (!flag) {

            trim = "Letra:" + ch + " se repite " + count + " veces ";
             // trim is a String where I need to store this information
        }


}
```

Expected result:

1. I need to count the occurences for each character in the String: Message
2. Store this information in a txt file

Ex:

**newfile.txt** with these information inside:

```
H, 2 times
e, 2 times
l, 2 times
o, 3 times
w, 1 times
a, 1 times
r, 1 times
e, 1 times
y, 1 times
u, 1 times
```

//

I tried with this that someone post it:

trim = trim + "\n" + ch + ", " + count + " veces \n";

and the result was this in the file: ( it's closer )

Hello,Howareyou? H, 2 times e, 2 times l, 2 times o, 3 times ,, 1 times w, 1 times 
a, 1 times r, 1 times y, 1 times u, 1 times ?, 1 times

Comment: To expand on @jonnyGold: Can you explain what result you wanted, and/or give the desired result for this particular input?

Comment: maybe translating the output would also help... this is an intl web site

Comment: The output says "Letter:H is repeated 1 times", "Letter:o is repeated 3 times", etc.

Comment: I edit my code so know It's clear to understand

Comment: @RenatoGama: intl == english ?

Comment: @m4g4bu: isn't this a homework for you by any chance? If so, please retag your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11278756/1484294

Comment: It's true. We can follow up here

Answer (score 0):

The problems start here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < third.length; i++) {

        if (ch == third[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
```

I can think of two solutions. The Correct Way is to use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) from characters to counts. If you do that, you can replace your entire for loop (not just the excerpted part above) with something along the lines of:

```
Map letters = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for(char c : third) {
  Integer raw_count = letters.get(c);
  int count = raw_count == null ? 0 : raw_count.intValue();
  letters.put(c, count + 1);
}
```

And then iterate through the map and print out its values. Comment if that part's confusing.

If you've never heard of a map before, now would be a good time to learn about them. If you *can't* use a map (homework...) then I'm certainly not providing a full code sample. But you can work around it with an array. Create a 26-element int array. Then you can do something like `letters[c - 'a']++`. Take a moment to digest that--we're saying the first element in the array is the count of `a`s, the second is the number of `b`s, etc. Initially these are all 0. Then we take the character we're looking at (`c`), subtract from it so that it's between `0` and `25` (not 97 and 122), and increment the total there.

Answer (score 0):

The [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) way:

```
Multiset<String> count = HashMultiset.create(Lists.charactersOf(message.replaceAll(" ", ""));
Files.write(Joiner.on("\n").join(Iterables.transform(count.entrySet(),
    new Function<Entry<String>, String>() {
        @Override public String apply(Entry<String> entry) {
            return String.format("%s, %d times", entry.getElement(), entry.getCount());
        }
    }, new File("whatever.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function countOccurrences() {

String Message = "Hello, how are you?"
String trim = Mensaje.replaceAll(" ", "");


char[] third = trim.toCharArray();

for (int counter = 0; counter < third.length; counter++) {

    if (ch == ',') {
        continue;
    }

    char ch = third[counter];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < third.length; i++) {

        if (ch == third[i]) {
            count++;
        }
    }


    boolean flag = false;
    for (int j = counter - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (ch == third[j]) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if (!flag) {

        trim = "Letra:" + ch + " se repite " + count + " veces ";
         // trim is a String where I need to store this information
    }
```

}

Comment: I've a question, if I need to create a counter for each word.. how can I do? ex:     if ( third[i] == "A" ) {   counterA++ }

Comment: Did not the code in my answer work ? I think there is no problem with the counter .